# OpenAL Library Linking With cMake

Tags: c, cmake, linker, openal

I'm trying to get a grasp on audio programming in C with OpenAL. I prefer CLion as an IDE to Visual Studio, but that generally means having to deal with cmake stuff and I ran into an issue regarding this. Right now I'm just trying to link the library (as in getting the definitions of the OpenAL functions) but it seems I've got something out of place. Here's the CMakeLists.txt file,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(AudioTest C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(OPENAL_LIBRARY  "C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenAL 1.1 SDK/libs/Win64/") //OpenAL Installed here

find_package(OpenAL REQUIRED)

add_executable(AudioTest main.c)
target_link_libraries(AudioTest "${OPENAL_LIBRARY}")
```

The Cmake file compiles (or reloads) fine on it's own. But when I try to run this simple program,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <al.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    alGetError();
    return 0;
}
```

I end up with this,
`undefined reference to '_imp__alGetError'`

Could I get some pointers to what I might be missing?

Comment: Your `set(OPENAL_LIBRARY ...` is plainly wrong, remove it.

Comment: Did that and now it can't find the library at all,
`Could NOT find OpenAL (missing: OPENAL_LIBRARY)`

Comment: You should try another SDK as https://www.openal.org/links/ suggests. At least https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft should play nicely with cmake.